# Загрузить приложение с внешней ссылкой

Tags: phonegap

С помощью jquery mobile привел сайт к мобильному виду.
Теперь, чтобы сконвертировать его в .apk или другие платформы через phonegap я отправляю его и все проходит. 
Но как заставить приложение подключиться к серверу. Ведь вся информация у меня хранится в БД. И php код, тоже не срабатывает.
Где и в какой строчке нужно указать ссылку  на сервер?

Comment: Приложение в фонгапе работает также как и в браузере. Только адресной строки нет. Объясните подробнее, что там происходит или какая ошибка выходит? 
Вам просто надо отправлять обычные Ajax-запросы на сервер и получать их желательно в формате JSON.

Comment: Необходимо достать информацию с БД Mysql. 
Где прописать путь к БД, пользователя, пароль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы непосредственно с телефона никак эту информацию именно из базы не достанете. Все что вам надо сделать, так это на сервере, на php (или на том, на чем у вас серверная часть), сделать все необходимые операции с извлечением данных и отправлять их в формате JSON в ответ на ajax-запрос с телефона. При этом, операция абсолютна аналогична с тем, как это делается из браузера телефона или компьютера.

Еще что вам надо знать, так это то, как разрешить отправлять запросы на сервер при помощи AJAX. Для этого вам надо внести ваш домен в whitelist. Подробно это описано на сайте фонгапа. [Вот](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide) ссылка конкретней.